# Push data to array and then iterate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to grab a bunch of data in a for statement, push it to an object array and then extract it ? i.e.

```
var d = {
    city: [{
       region: '',
       name: '',
       type: ''
    }]
}
```

I am getting data from `cityList[i]` - which has around 10 of each - like

```
for(var i=0, city; i < cityList.len; i++ {
      city = cityList[i]

     //manipulate a bit 

    d.city.push(data, data1, data2) //i.e. region, name, type

}
```

Then I want to show that data from `d.city` ? How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set data to array shold look:

```
d.city.push({
   region: data,
   name: data2,
   type: data3
});
```

To retrieve data from `d.city` you can use:

```
$.each(d.city, function() {
  console.log(this.region);
  console.log(this.name); // etc
});
```

Comment: is the way I am pushing it correct ? i.e. I want `d.city` to contain ten lots of region,name,type ?

Comment: great thanks I think that was my mistake :) i.e. with the array!

Comment: @Andy Great Welcome, If any answer help you then you should accept that.

Comment: yeah its the time limit thing :)

Comment: `d.city[i] = { 
regin:data, 
name:data2, 
type:data3 };`

would be faster than using `push` :)

@Andy Please accept the thecodeparadox's answer.